# Channel form submission decryption error

Tags: safecracker, forms, channel-form

I'm having an issue with EE Channel form, when I post I just get the following error:

```
The form you submitted contained the following errors  
Decryption of form settings failed.  
Return to Previous Page
```

The code I use to display and submit the form is literally taken from the docs, replacing with the relevant channel name with no other changes.

I've gone through all my sites config in the admin area and even disabled **Process form data in Secure Mode?** just to test it out, but still received the same error.

I've searched as far as I can think on Google and the EE forums with no luck, if anyone could shed some light i'd really appreciate it!

EE Version : v2.7.3

***Edit***

The code I use to generate the channel form is:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="exhibitors" return="success" entry_id="{embed:entry}" author_only="yes" }
  {!-- all field tags --}
{/exp:channel:form}
```

I ran a clean install of expression engine today and migrated templates etc, the channel form was working perfectly for a while and now suddenly it's happening again.

When I've  looked a bit more into the source this is whats getting generated at the top:

```
<form id="publishForm" method="post" action="http://localhost/handbook/company_profile?  
RET=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fhandbook%2Fcompany_profile&amp;URI=handbook%2Fcompany_profile&amp;
XID=&amp;return_url=handbook%2Fcompany_profile &amp;author_id=1&amp;channel_id=1&amp;
entry_id=0&amp;ACT=7&amp;meta=DLauS6rZ7%2BgnIQ%2Bt5HKmwk4ufzbKqkP..etc
enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="hiddenFields">
 <input type="hidden" name="RET"  value="http://localhost/handbook/company_profile">
 <input type="hidden" name="URI" value="handbook/company_profile">
 <input type="hidden" name="XID" value="0d2db0442daeaf6dc776353853a581f71ed14de6">
 <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="handbook/company_profile">
 <input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="channel_id" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="0">
 <input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="7">
 <input type="hidden" name="meta" value="DLauS6rZ7+gnIQ+t5HKmwk4ufzbKqkPEXm1hjiftiSGFz..etc">
```

If I inspect element in chrome, remove everything after the company_profile? part and post the form, it works fine, but for some reason its adding all the hidden inputs onto the action and then I assume when it's posted its all getting added again and failing? :/ how or why it decided to suddenly do this I don't know...

Comment: anything on your side what can change or broke inputs data? Did you try diff browsers?

Comment: I don't think so, the template I'm using to test has no styling or JS (aside from what channel form brings in itself). I consider myself quite savvy with EE and have used channel form before but this is the first time i've encountered this error, completely stumped :/. I've tested the form in Safari, Firefox and Chrome with the same error.

Comment: do you have it online? Is it you local machine or server? Could you please publish your channel:form first tag (with parameter etc.). In html output - what do you have in input name="meta"?

Comment: I just updated my question, it happens both on a live server and locally.

Comment: if you think it possible, i can check it on your server. send me email - max at eec.ms

Comment: so is this solve?
How it is solve?